# Call javascript function from Java (Groovy) class

Tags: java, javascript, groovy

I have a javascript function (very big one!) that I need its functionality in a Java (Groovy) class. It is a simple calendar converter. I can rewrite it in groovy but just want to know if it is possible to call javascript function from a java (groovy) method? I guess functional testing libraries like selenium and Canoo should have  something like this, am I right?
PS: I don't want to wake up a real-world browser in order to use its JS runtime env.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, it is possible to use the [Scripting API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/) provided as part of the [`javax.script`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-frame.html) package, available from Java 6.

The following is a Groovy example which executes a little bit of Javascript:

```
import javax.script.*

manager = new ScriptEngineManager()
engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript")

javascriptString = """
obj = {"value" : 42}
print(obj["value"])
"""

engine.eval(javascriptString)  // prints 42
```

It is not necessary to call a browser to execute Javascript when using the Scripting API, but one should keep in mind that browser-specific features (probably the DOM-related functionalities) will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/doc.html), an implementation of JavaScript language in Java. Here is example of [calling JavaScript function from java](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/tutorial.html#callingJSfuns), but you can do it from groovy also.